# MongoDb compass complex filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in mongo.
Sample single entry

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6278dc35b07e447b14feef57"
    },
    "formId": "6278d9f7b07e447b14feef54",
    "formData": {
            "0": {
            "value": "297CSSIB"
        },
        "1": {
            "value": "Alba Gonzalez"
        },
        "2": {
            "value": "Concentrix"
        },
        "3": {
            "value": "San Salvador"
        }
    }
}
```

now I want to filter with formId and value San Salvador. (where formId = "6278d9f7b07e447b14feef54" and index 3 value of formData is San Salvador)

I am unable to find any solution for that Please help.

Comment: Have you tried it on your own?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current document structure, it is only possible, if the value San Salvador, is always present at index 3.

In that case, the following query should work:

```
db.collection.find({
  formId: "6278d9f7b07e447b14feef54",
  "formData.3.value": "San Salvador"
})
```

However, I suggest you change your document structure so that formData is an array since it's keys are just indexes:

```
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6278dc35b07e447b14feef57"
    },
    "formId": "6278d9f7b07e447b14feef54",
    "formData": [
      {
        "value": "297CSSIB"
      },
      {
        "value": "Alba Gonzalez"
      },
      {
        "value": "Concentrix"
      },
      {
        "value": "San Salvador"
      }
    ]
  }
```

In this way, the query can be more generic, rather than index specific:

```
db.collection.find({
  formId: "6278d9f7b07e447b14feef54",
  "formData.value": "San Salvador"
})
```

Comment: Thanks your suggestion worked. with mongoDbCompass.

{formId:"6278d9f7b07e447b14feef54","formData.3.value":"San Salvador"}